# returning a const reference to a string

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm building a secret message class which has a vector of lines in a message and number of maximum times each message can be viewed. I'm trying to overload the [] operator in order to be able to see a message.

For example: If I want to initialize the following vector of strings, I should be able to do...

```
vector<string> m = {
    "Here is the first line",
    "I have a second line as well",
    "Third line of message"};

//initialize message - each line may be viewed a maximum of two times
SelfDestructingMessage sdm(m, 2);

cout << sdm[0] << endl;
//outputs "Here is the first line" and decrements remaining views of first line by one
```

My question is, I declared the operator in the header file and then defined it in a function file as follows:

```
string SelfDestructingMessage::operator[](size_t index){
    return const string & message[index];
}
```

Thus, I should be able to see the actual message using the [] operator which takes a size_t argument (index). It should return a const reference to the message string that was indexed from the vector of messages specific to the object.

But when compiling, I get a "error: expected primary-expression before 'const' return const string & message[index];"

Any idea on the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const string &` part needs to be in the signature of the function. There is no need to explicitly convert `message[index]` to a `const string&` in the body, it happens automatically:

```
const string& SelfDestructingMessage::operator[](size_t index){
    return message[index];
}
// also update the declaration
```

For next time, please try to write a [minimal, compilable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It really helps the people that try to answer your question.